# How do I make my directory writable by Gunicorn?

Tags: django, sqlite, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I have an app in digital ocean, when I try to create a new user or item, I receive the following error http://pastebin.com/tGV440FU

```
OperationalError at /accounts/signin/
unable to open database file
```

Can you tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: What does the DATABASES section of your settings.py look like?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/J822tems (the base settings) and http://pastebin.com/bTAhMv1E (the production settings)